# I am removing nth character from string, but when I enter the nth number as (length(string) + 1) it gives me result as same as my original string

Tags: python, string

This is my code:

```
str1 = "Hello How are you dude?"
print("\nInitial String :" + str1)
n = int(input("Enter index number to remove character from above string :"))


if n <= len(str1):
    first_part = str1[:n]
    second_part = str1[n+1:]
    final_string = first_part + second_part
    print("Result String :", final_string)
else:
    print("Your Entered Number is out of the range..!!")
```

his is my output:

```
Initial String :Hello How are you dude?
Enter index number to remove character from above string :23
Result String : Hello How are you dude?
```

When I was give input a number of total length of string + 1, it gives me output same as my original string. You can see in code I mention output as well. How it will happen? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: A title is a short resume, you don't explain the whole problem in it ;)

Comment: Check the length of str1.

Answer (score 1):

As `str` is 0-indexed, your condition should be

```
if n < len(str1): # and not <=
```

---

Giving

```
if n < len(str1):
    final_string = str1[:n] + str1[n + 1:]
    print(f"Removed char '{str1[n]}'")       # Useful for debug purpose
    print("Result String :", final_string)
else:
    print("Your Entered Number is out of the range..!!")
```

Comment: Ya get it, I was made very silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In your *if condition* you have mentioned if `n<=len(str)` which becomes True if you give input as 23 and the line following that will make the value of first_part equal to the original string indexed from 0 to 22 which has a length of 23 itself, same as the original string.

In other words, you are trying to remove the 24th character (n=23) from a string of length 23, that is why you are getting the full string.